# In Laravel 5.5 Bootstrap Glyphicons Not Displaying Correctly Offline

Tags: laravel

I'm getting an issue with Bootstrap glyphicons in Laravel 5.5 when working offline especially, when using the class glyphicon glyphicon-home, it displays the copyright sign instead of the expected home icon.
I have confirmed that Bootstrap CSS and JS files are included correctly,

Here's a snippet of my code where I'm using the glyphicon:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span>
```

Comment: dont use external assets ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Page need internet to get load. If not get load - does not know that the glyphicons exists on webside. Simple. If you want to see web offline read about CACHE.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do is to clear your cache or put the glyphicon sign into a  or simply try font awesome it is as good as glyphicon.

Answer (score 0):

I have used font awesome online and now, everything is working fine. Thanks.